What is an efficient way to listen on all ports?
I have a requirement that all ports 1-65535 are open however i don't have access to the network and so my workaround before this i.e. opening port 22 (and a few others) involved opening ports on vpn with a dedicated ip address forwarded to this machine though the vpn.
Furthermore, In this instance - I found that the only way to make ports appear "open" on a port checker website just as an example (to the outside world) on my external address, was to use ncat command to make ubuntu listen on the specific port numbers or a service running on them like sshd. If i do the same with all ports in the range 1-65535 it would slow everything to a crawl I discovered mabye because its too many ports.
I know how to open ports in the ufw firewall and i don't think that doing that alone will meet the requirements for the cloud service i am trying to accommodate currently, its called lambda, if anyone's ever heard of that and I'm integrating it with another pinfi network, and they say all ports need to be open.
pinfi is sort of like defi. What is an efficient way of making it listen on those ports or does anybody know if I really don't need them exposed to the outside since my vpn is already open on those ports outside my local network although a port checker for example (https://www.ipvoid.com/port-scan/) cant tell that on my external ip unless i have a service listening from my local Linux workstation.
Its funny because it sort of resembles making a switch listen on different ports.

What do you mean by "open"? Accessible from "outside"? A process listening to each of the 65,536 ports? Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

I'd open a single port, and use iptables in DNAT mode to redirect all other ports to it.
iptables \
    -t nat \
    -I PREROUTING \
    -p tcp \
    -d 1.2.3.4 \
    \! --dport 12345 \
    -j DNAT \
    --to-dest 1.2.3.4:12345

where 1.2.3.4 is your local IP address, and 12345 is the port you opened with netcat.
